# How to create a sequential range in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table where each row has a From and a To:

```
From|To  
  A | B 
  C | D
  B | C
  D | E
```

And I need to order them in a sequence where "To" in the first row is the "From" of the following and so on.

The result should be ordered like this:

```
From|To 
   A| B  
   B| C  
   C| D  
   D| E
```

The main problem is finding the From that follows the To in the previous record.

Comment: What is your RDBMS, please?

Comment: Also, can you clarify whether you have a table already like the second result and are struggling to order it, or you're trying to create the second result you posted from the first?

Comment: Sorry, it's MS SQL server 2008

Comment: Is it possible to have cases like `A | D`?  How woud that be ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got your question right. Why don't you just sort?

```
;with cte as
(  
select 'B' as "From", 'C' as "To"
union
select 'A', 'B'
union
select 'C', 'D'
)
select "From", "To"
  from cte
 order by "From";
```

(You don't need the cte/union stuff in your query, it's just for the sake of sample data.)

If you want to list only entries with successors:

```
;with cte as
(  
select 'B' as "From", 'C' as "To"
union
select 'A', 'B'
union
select 'C', 'D'
union
select 'F', 'G'
)
select "From", "To"
  from cte
 where exists(select *
                from cte cte2
               where cte2."From" = cte."To")
    or exists(select *
                from cte cte3
               where cte3."To" = cte."From")
 order by "From";
```

Btw: Try using other column names than "From" and "To" as they are reserved statements that have to be used with "" (ANSI) or [] (T SQL).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> declare @v table (ffrom varchar(10), fto varchar(10));
> insert into @v values
> ('e', 'f'),
> ('a', 'b'),
> ('g', 'h'),
> ('c', 'd');
>
> select * 
> from @v
> order by ffrom;
> ```
>
> GO
>
> ```
> ffrom | fto
> :---- | :--
> a     | b  
> c     | d  
> e     | f  
> g     | h
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=deb75fcfaf416225115b5e979fc95551)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select from, to, 1 as lev
      from t
      where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.to = t.from)
      union all
      select t.from, t.to, cte.lev + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.to = t.from
     )
select to, from
from cte
order by lev, to;
```

Note that this is affected by the maximum recursion depth, but it will work fine on four rows.